# Why last name input disappear?

Tags: php, html

i try to make function which makes it easy to use input text in function_html.php

```
function form_input($label, $name, $type="text", $class="", $placeholder="", $attr=""){
   echo'<div class="form-group">
   <label for="'.$name.'">'.$label.'</label>
   <input type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'" class="'.$class.'" placeholder="'.$placeholder.'" '.$attr.'>
   </div>';
}
```

and than i make a form that call the form_input function in login_view.php

```
<form id="register-form" action="<?= BASE_PATH ?>/login/register-submit" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                     <?php
   if(isset($data['msg'])){
      if(is_array($data['msg'])){
?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <ul>
<?php
      foreach($data['msg'] as $error){
         echo "<li>$error</li>";
      }
?>
      </ul>
   </div>
<?php
      }else{
         echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>$data[msg]</div>";
      }
   }
   echo "
   <label for='username'>Username</label>
   <div class='form-group input-group'>
   <span class='input-group-addon'>@</span>
   <input type='text' name='username' id='usernamer' class='form-control' placeholder='' required data-error='Username 6-8 a-z'>
   </div>";
form_input("Password", "passwordr", "password", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Password can't be null");
form_input("Re-Password", "passwordr2", "password", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Password can't be null");
form_input("Email", "email", "email", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Email can't be null");
form_input("First Name", "fname", "text", "form-control", "", "required data-error='First Name 2-10 a-z");
form_input("Last Name", "lname", "text", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Last Name 2-10 a-z");
?>
                                </form>
```

but `Last Name` field disappear
[image: form screen shoot]

Comment: There is an issue in `"required data-error='Password can't be null"`.. You are missing the end `'` in all of them.

Comment: @MilanChheda -,,-" how can i forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 form_input("Password", "passwordr", "password", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Password can't be null'");
 form_input("Re-Password", "passwordr2", "password", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Password can't be null'");
 form_input("Email", "email", "email", "form-control", "", "required data-error='Email can't be null'");
 form_input("First Name", "fname", "text", "form-control", "", "required data-error='First Name 2-10 a-z'");
 form_input("Last Name", "lname", "text", "form-control", "", "required data-error='First Name 2-10 a-z'");
```

Replace your code with this code. You have missed `'` in `required data-error`